# PHP ODBC to Db2 field name with ñ

Tags: php, db2, odbc

I'm on a Windows 2008 enviroment with Ibm ODBC driver installed and configured, PHP version 7.2.3. I can do querys without problems until now that I have a field name with Ñ character.

Working with Codeigniter framework.

**SELECT ISTYLÑ FROM tablename**

I'm getting this error on Select execution:
**Símbolo Ã no válido**

I can see that field name **istylñ** is replaced with **istylÃ±** when executed the statement.

I think this is related with PHP, not ODBC driver itself. Just to check I did the same Select statement, on same machine, with Excel odbc and data was retrieved successfully.

Thanks,

Felipe

Comment: Which version of PHP?   What is the codepage (codeset, CCSID) of the Db2 database/table/column/tablespace ?  Do you know about iconv ? http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: Hello, php version 7.2.3. Don't know codeset of Db2. Tryed with iconv (with different conversion options) with no luck.

Comment: It's your job to discover basic facts about your database such as the encoding. One reason why Excel works is that it may handle unicode/utf-8 encoded data, while your code might not handle it correctly. The database codeset/codepage/CCSID determines the encoding.

Comment: Hi Mao, thanks for you reply. I received this information from DBA: Codeset: UTF-8 Codepage: IBM37 CCSID 011C

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
$sql = "SELECT ISTYLÑ FROM tablename";<br>
$sql = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $sql);

$this->db->query($sql);
```

Thanks mao for your guidance.